# Proof that matrix exponent elements belong to certain span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

I am to prove the following proposition using S+N decomposition.

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ - that is, an $n\times n$ matrix over some field $\mathbb{F}$, and $\mu_1,...,\mu_l$ its eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicities $n_1,...,n_l$. Write $\mu_q=\alpha_q+i\beta_q$, with $\alpha_q,\beta_q\in\mathbb{R}$ Then
\begin{align*}
   &\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}\\
   &\{e^{tA}\}_{ij}\in \text{Span}_\mathbb{C}\{t^p e^{\mu_q t} | 1\leq q\leq l, 0\leq p \leq n_q\}\\
   &\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}\\
   &\{e^{tA}\}_{ij}\in \text{Span}_\mathbb{R}\{t^p e^{\mu_q t}\cos(\beta_q t),t^p e^{\mu_q t}\sin(\beta_q t) | 1\leq q\leq l, 0\leq p \leq n_q\}
\end{align*}

But I'm unsure how to get started, even.
For S+N decomposition, I know that a square matrix A can be 'decomposed' into a diagonalizable matrix S and a nilpotent matrix N which commute, such that the exponential $e^{tA}=e^{t(S+N)}=e^{tS}e^{tN}$.
Furthermore, the exponential of diagonal or nilpotent matrices can be computed with relative ease.

For a nilpotent $n\times n$ matrix, the exponential series terminates for $i=n$, e.g.
\begin{equation*}
e^{tN} = \mathbf{Id} +tN+...\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}N^{n-1}
\end{equation*}

And for a diagonal matrix $D=\text{Diag}\{\lambda_1,...\lambda_n\}$, you get a diagonal matrix where every entry is just the exponentials, e.g. $e^{tD}=\text{Diag}\{e^{t\lambda_1},...,e^{t\lambda_n}\}$.

However, as I understand it the decomposition matrix $S$ is *diagonalizable*, but not necessarily diagonal. So how would the product $e^{tN}e^{tS}$ shape up? I'm only certain of the $e^{tN}$-part.

Secondly, I don't see the connection with the spans given in the proposition, and I'm not sure how to verify that all the matrix entries belong to those spans.